# What does this MATLAB class to and why isn't it working on my PC?

Tags: matlab, function, class, oop, syntax

The very first one in this documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/getting-familiar-with-classes.html

The class is:

```
classdef BasicClass
   properties
      Value
   end
   methods
      function r = roundOff(obj)
         r = round([obj.Value],2);
      end
      function r = multiplyBy(obj,n)
         r = [obj.Value] * n;
      end
   end
end
```

When I run it this way

```
a = BasicClass
a.Value = pi/3;
```

It works fine and does what it should but this piece of code

```
a = BasicClass(pi/3);
```

Gives the following error:

*"Error using round*

*Too many input arguments."*

What does it mean? (I'm using R2014a) Is it stupid to use oop in Matlab? LOL

Answer (score 1):

Your error message doesn't look correct compared with the code, whichever your missing a class constructor (as is mentioned at the half way down the help link):

```
classdef BasicClass
  properties
    Value
  end
  methods

    % Class constructor -> which you can pass pi/3 into.
    function obj = BasicClass ( varargin )
      if nargin == 1
        obj.Value = varargin{1};
      end
    end

    % Your Methods
    function r = roundOff(obj)
      r = round([obj.Value],2);
    end
    function r = multiplyBy(obj,n)
      r = [obj.Value] * n;
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now this code gives error
    roundOff(a)
It says:Error using round
Too many input arguments.
Error in BasicClass/roundOff (line 16).

Oh I guess it's not the problem of class, maybe my round function is outdated. Thanks again!

Comment: @ĬnfernalSeraphím you are not calling the `roundOff` function as `myObj.roundOff(foo)` right? Or as `myClass.roundOff(myObj)`? The first argument refers to the object calling the function. So if you have a `BasicClass` object `bc`, then `bc.roundOff();` rounds `bc` to nearest integer. Further, a constructor is not mandatory, in case no constructor is defined Matlab uses the default constructor. Still a class should always have a constructor defined.